# my telegram bot can't receive messages from other bots in group chat

Tags: telegram-bot

I can see messages sent from normal users in group chat with getUpdates.
but no info from messages that other bots have sent.
Is there any method that I should use other than getUpdates to receive them too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bot FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots), bots will not be able to see messages from other bots regardless of mode.